# How to Masking account number in sql (NETEZZA)

Tags: sql, netezza

I have an 8 digit account number I want to mask last three to XXX
I am working with IBM Netezza database.

for eg: 34567890
output: 34567XXX

Could someone please tell me the syntax for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
select strleft(account, length(account) - 3) || 'XXX'
```

Or if all accounts are exactly 8 characters:

```
select strleft(account, 5) || 'XXX'
```

Comment: I am getting error 'len(int8) ' does not exist unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types , you may need to add explicit typecasts.

Comment: @taashu . . . .Oops.  That should be `length()`.

Comment: thanks length() works but iam getting output as 10000xxx instead of the first four digits from the account number. How can I fix it?

Comment: @taashu . . . `strleft()` (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/r_sqlext_strleft.html) takes the left-most characters of `account`, so I have to assume that those are `'0000'`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

repeat('*',length(substr(accountnr,1,length(account_nr)-4))-1)||substr(accountnr) -3,4)

The above query will help to mask the first four digits of your account number